# Optimization 101 for electrical engineers…Where to start from?

Tags: optimization, self-learning

I have never taken any optimization class. From an electrical engineering point of view, how should I approach learning this field? What kind of information I should be looking at in my problem to determine in which class my problem falls into? What are the most useful optimization methods and techniques specific to digital signal processing and digital communication problems? Any online help and book recommendation will be much appreciated.

Comment: Mathematicians tend not to be familiar with electrical engineering. It would be helpful if you could post the specific problem.

Comment: I posted my problem on the following link.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086031/trouble-with-formulation-of-objective-function-constraint-optimization

Comment: @ Matt. But thats just one question. I need to learn this stuff and I don't know from where to make a start. When I look at Math and ISYE courses related to optimization, they sound in some different language. I understand that electrical engineering is an application area for this theory but how can one apply without knowing what it is? How to bridge this gap, is my real concern?

Comment: I won't be much help in this specifically, but I would guess that if you don't understand what goes on in the courses then you likely don't have the prerequisites and should probably check what those are.